# fetching one row at a time sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I have a query that looks like this:

```
select * from myTable order by id desc
```

but one of the columns is XML and has a large amount of data. So if I return all the rows it takes forever.
Can can I modify my query so that I only fetch one row at a time?
I'm using a simple call to return a dataset for this query like so:

```
DataSet DataSet = new DataSet();
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter =
                new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn) };
            dataAdapter.Fill(DataSet);
        }
        return DataSet;
```

Comment: Use a `DataReader` instead of a `DataSet`, and you can read the results one row at a time.

Comment: To add on to voithos comment, not only do you read them one row at a time, but as soon as .NET receives the next row from the server, it's ready in the DataReader. It does not wait for all of them.